# How to run the same TestSuite multiple times unittest texttestrunner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run tests with multiple builds of a product running them once. Here is example of the code:

```
import unittest

suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("./tests")
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

for build in [build1, build2]:
    get_the_build(build)
    runner.run(suite)
```

The first iteration works well, but on the start of the second one an error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Path/to/my/folder/run_tests.py", line 9, in <module>
    runner.run(suite)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\runner.py", line 176, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What is happening? What result `runner` calls? And why does it fail? Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, well, well. I have spent the last hour of my life looking at the code of `unittest` in GitHub, which can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/unittest). I just went to the code of `suite.py` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/unittest/suite.py#L92)), one of the files in the error you are getting. This is the actual code of `TestSuite.run`:

```
def run(self, result, debug=False):
    topLevel = False
    if getattr(result, '_testRunEntered', False) is False:
        result._testRunEntered = topLevel = True

    for index, test in enumerate(self):
        if result.shouldStop:
            break

        if _isnotsuite(test):
            self._tearDownPreviousClass(test, result)
            self._handleModuleFixture(test, result)
            self._handleClassSetUp(test, result)
            result._previousTestClass = test.__class__

            if (getattr(test.__class__, '_classSetupFailed', False) or
                getattr(result, '_moduleSetUpFailed', False)):
                continue

        if not debug:
            test(result)
        else:
            test.debug()

        if self._cleanup:
            self._removeTestAtIndex(index)

    if topLevel:
        self._tearDownPreviousClass(None, result)
        self._handleModuleTearDown(result)
        result._testRunEntered = False
    return result
```

So, basically, what this code does is to iterate over each test the suite has and invoke it:

```
for index, test in enumerate(self):
    ...
    if not debug:
        test(result)  # This is the line throwing the error
    ...
```

As you can see, that loop iterates over the suite itself, so I it must have an `__iter__` method defined *somewhere*. After 5 minutes of not finding it inside the class `TestSuite`, I realized is the parent class who has such method. This is what I found in `BaseTestSuite`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._tests)
```

Basically, it just returns an *iterator* of the tests. In that moment, such line of code, was a high wall I couldn't surepass. But I didn't give up and went back to `TestSuite.run` definition and, miraculously, I spotted the next lines:

```
...
if self._cleanup:
    self._removeTestAtIndex(index)
...
```

And that made me wonder: *"Are the tests being removed? Let me investigate"*. Then I was enlightened, because inside `_removeTestAtIndex` I spotted this line:

```
self._tests[index] = None
```

End of story. So, after running all of your tests the first time, they got converted into nothing more than `None`: the list of tests inside the suite ended up being a list of `None`s (`[None, None, ..., None]`).

So, **how do you prevent such behaviour**? Just turn off the `_cleanup` flag inside the suite. This should work:

#### Answer

```
import unittest

suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("./tests")
suite._cleanup = False  # Prevent such cleanup

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

for build in [build1, build2]:
    get_the_build(build)
    runner.run(suite)
```

Sorry for the long story but, besides showing you how to solve your issue, I also wanted to teach you how to debug whatever.

Let me know if this actually worked for you. Otherwise, tell me what went wrong.

Comment: Your solution does not work, but your answer is the best answer I can imagine. It gives more than just an answer.

Comment: I had an idea that tests are deleted from the suite, but I was misled by the `suite.countTestCases()`. I called it before the run and after the run and it showed the same number. Now I made one more step and called `print(suite)` and it actually returns `None` (though `suite.countTestCases()`still returns a number). Flag changes nothing. So, the right solution is to discover tests on each iteration.

Comment: @Nick Instead of `suite._cleanup = False`, try `unittest.BaseTestSuite._cleanup = False`.

Answer (score 1):

Feels like a horrible hack, but making a deep copy of the suite each time before running it solved the problem for me:

```
import unittest
import copy

suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("./tests")
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

for build in [build1, build2]:
    get_the_build(build)
    runner.run(copy.deepcopy(suite))
```